# mysql query returning same fields referencing 2 different foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

kind of a hard question to word but here are the the tables:

***STUDENT**

ID pk

ASSIGNED_ADVISOR_ID fk ref (DEP_FACULTY.ID)

FNAME

LNAME

***DEP_FACULTY**

ID

FNAME

LNAME

***ADVISE_HIST**

STUDENT_ID

ACTUAL_ADVISOR_ID fk ref (DEP_FACULTY.ID)

**heres the problem:**

A student can be advised by a faculty member other than their `ASSIGNED_ADVISOR_ID` (which is `ACTUAL_ADVISOR_ID`) and I need a query, joining these 3 tables, that will return a students name, assigned advisor name, and actual advisor name (among other things I wont list).

**my query so far:**

```
select
 CONCAT(STUDENT.LNAME,', ',STUDENT.FNAME), 
 CONCAT(DEP_FACULTY.LNAME,', ',DEP_FACULTY.FNAME) as "ASSIGNED ADVISOR",
 ***need a field here for actual advisor***
from 
  STUDENT 
  join DEP_FACULTY on STUDENT.ASSIGNED_ADVISOR_ID=DEP_FACULTY.ID
  left join ADVISE_HIST on STUDENT.ID=ADVISE_HIST.STUDENT_ID;
```

Is there any way to display the `DEP_FACULTY.LNAME` and `FNAME` again, but referencing the ACTUAL advisor this time?

Or do I need to add redundancy to `ADVISE_HIST` (`ADVISE_HIST.DEP_FACULTY_LNAME` and `ADVISE_HIST.DEP_FACULTY_FNAME`) to properly return this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
 CONCAT(STUDENT.LNAME,', ',STUDENT.FNAME), 
 CONCAT(DEP_FACULTY.LNAME,', ',DEP_FACULTY.FNAME) as `ASSIGNED ADVISOR`,
 CONCAT(ACTUAL.LNAME, ', ', ACTUAL.FNAME) AS `ACTUAL ADVISOR`
from 
  STUDENT 
  join DEP_FACULTY on STUDENT.ASSIGNED_ADVISOR_ID=DEP_FACULTY.ID
  left join ADVISE_HIST on STUDENT.ID=ADVISE_HIST.STUDENT_ID
  /* JOIN again between DEP_FACULTY and ADVISE_HIST with an alias */
  LEFT JOIN DEP_FACULTY AS ACTUAL ON ADVISE_HIST.ACTUAL_ADVISOR_ID = ACTUAL.ID
```

Comment: Only it should probably be LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @AndriyM Not sure without testing - since its a LEFT JOIN between `STUDENT` and `ADVISE_HIST`, that should already be taken care of.

Comment: Yes, because of that left join students without advise history could be returned, but with your inner join they would be discarded, because your join would attempt to match a NULL `ACTUAL_ADVISOR_ID` to an `ACTUAL.ID` and fail.

Comment: For future readers sake, the end of your answer query ACTUAL.DEP_FACULTY_ID should have just been ACTUAL.ID, other than that this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.